# How to get the employees who have a salary that is more than 50% of the average salary?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables - `employees` and `departments`.

The `employees` table has the following columns: `emp_id`, `salary`, `dep_id`.

The `departments` table has the following: `dep_id`, `department_name`, `manager`.

Now, I am trying to get the employee_ids of the employees who have a salary that is more than 50% of the average salary as well as the name of the department manager.

I have written this so far:

```
SELECT emp_id, manager
FROM
  (SELECT (salary / AVG(salary) * 100) AS percentage
  FROM employees )
INNER JOIN departments
   ON employees.dep_id = departments.dep_id
WHERE percentage > 50
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: no such column: emp_id
```

I am using the following to execute my code: https://www.sqltutorial.org/seeit/

Comment: You select `employee_id` which (according to your stated columns) should probably be `emp_id`.

Comment: Just changed it, and still getting the same error - is it my code?

Comment: It's good programming practice to _qualify_ all columns, like `employees.dep_id` instead of just `dep_id`.

Comment: Thanks for that - juust changed my code to that in my compiler, and still getting the error.

Comment: How does the data indicate who is a manager of a department? Is it where `manager_id` is `null` in the `employees` table?

Comment: I think so, but even if I do not select ```manager_id```, I still get the same error - do I need a ```GROUP BY``` clause?

Comment: Maybe I need to use CTE?

Comment: Do you need the average salary of _all_ employees, or the average of employees in that department?

Comment: To make this question more clear, please provide your expected output from the query. It's not apparent how many rows you are expecting to be returned based on the demo dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my answer- this works on my data set.

```
SELECT employee_id, d.department_id
FROM employees
INNER JOIN departments as d
   ON employees.department_id = d.department_id
   
WHERE salary > (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM employees) * 1.5
```

Comment: `manager` should be `manager_id`, but that also gives the error "Error: misuse of aggregate function AVG()"

Comment: I just tried that, and I am getting that error @WOUNDEDStevenJones

Comment: Why multiply by 1.5?

Comment: because he wanted employees that make 50% more than the average salary. So average salary is the 1 and 50% of that is .5

Answer (score 0):

You can split the logic more easily using subqueries. So to find all employees that have a higher-than-average salary:

```
SELECT
    e.employee_id,
    e.manager_id,
    e.department_id
FROM employees e
WHERE salary > (
    SELECT AVG(salary) * 1.5 FROM employees
);
```

Then to find a list of all managers:

```
SELECT
    manager_id,
    email,
    department_id
FROM employees
WHERE manager_id IS NULL
```

Then you can combine these to get the final data:

```
SELECT
    e.employee_id,
    e.manager_id,
    e.department_id,
    managers.email
FROM employees e
JOIN (
  SELECT
    manager_id,
    email,
    department_id
  FROM employees
  WHERE manager_id IS NULL
) managers ON managers.department_id = e.department_id
WHERE salary > (
    SELECT AVG(salary) * 1.5 FROM employees
);
```

Returns the following:

```
e.employee_id   e.manager_id    e.department_id managers.email
100             null            9               steven.king@sqltutorial.org
101             100             9               steven.king@sqltutorial.org
102             100             9               steven.king@sqltutorial.org
```

If you need additional manager data (first/last name), you can edit the `managers` subquery to select the relevant columns from the `employees` table and include those new columns in the main `SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks for that, but where would I add the 50%, as I want to know which employees earn 50% more than the average?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part of your question. I updated my answer, but you'd just multiple the `AVG(salary)` by 1.5 to get that new value.